# Why does TFS 2010 installation not offer to install TFS on Win XP?

Tags: tfs, windows-xp, tfs-2010

I am installing TFS 2010 on a Win XP PC.  When I get to "Select features to install" it only offers to install the Team Foundation Build Service.  It does not offer to install Team Foundation Server.

Why oh why is this?

Comment: Because Microsoft decided not to support an older version of a client OS for a server product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XP is not a [supported operating system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253078%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Only 2003+ server operating systems are supported.

Edit - Just noticed my link was for TFS 2008 - Here's the list of OSes that [support TFS 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/system-requirements):

- Windows Vista® operating system with Service Pack 2 (both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, excluding Windows Vista Starter and Home Basic Editions)
- Windows 7® operating system (both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, excluding Windows 7 Starter Edition)
- Windows Server® 2003 (32-bit) with Service Pack 2 or later (all editions)
- Windows Server® 2003 R2 (32-bit) or later (all editions)
- Windows Server® 2008 (both 32-bit and 64-bit) with Service Pack 2 or later
- Windows Server® 2008 R2 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

Well.. it is a SERVER product.

However, considering you can install it on Vista or Windows 7 then they probably are doing things that just aren't supported under IIS 5.1